# htaccess problem

Tags: apache2

My problem is : when i create .htaccess file my browser shows 403 Forbidden
my htaccess code is

```
Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(img|css|port/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

My rewrite mod is enable index.php exists where is the problem.
When i delete or rename htaccess the problem is gone
this is my config

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have this in your .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

but you don't (or didn't post) a matching

```
</IfModule>
```

Also, you can look in Apache's error logs (usually /var/log/apache/error.log) for more detailed information about the 403 error you're seeing. If you can't figure out what the problem is from the error logs, you can add the lines with errors to your question and we can help see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should describe your condition and configuration clearly, so as not cause misunderstanding to know your condition and configuration.

Have you checked you phpinfo in Configuration > apache2handler > Loaded Modules there must be written **mod_rewrite** that show mod_rewrite enabled. If not, you should run this command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and then restart your apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you have done that things. Try to check your permission in your /var/www/.  Usually, the 403 forbidden error means that your file has bad permissions, **folders** is set to **755** and **files** to **644**.